# How i can solve StackOverflowError for android application?

Tags: java, android

** **I am a new android developer.I use a layout for android screen...the lauout design are****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/row1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".1" >
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".5"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".2" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/man" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".2" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/man" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".2" >
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".1" >
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="BRUCE LEE $ MAO ZEDONG"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:src="@drawable/clock" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="30 minute ago "
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:background="@drawable/backimage"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".5" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="4" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".2" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/defaultbi" />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SPECIAL OFFER 30%"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="8sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="prosato vai is a software enginure jhjdshjhjkfhjkfjksdjjdjjjkjiddsdj"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="8sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".4"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".5" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="2" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".5" >
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".8" >
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/pin" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="245 milles 22mb Baker Street London"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="8sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/cro" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="at Scroll Bar"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="8sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".1" >
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp" >

<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#a3a3a3" />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/row1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".1" >
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".8"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".8" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1.2" >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/man" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight=".8" >
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".1" >
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="4"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="JACKIE CHAN"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
android:src="@drawable/photo" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:text="photo "
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/clock" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:text="40 minute ago"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="4" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="2.5" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="fghghjdjdjfhdjfhjhjjjn  jhjhdfjds hjhdfjdnf " />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/threetwo"
    android:text="Agree"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>


</LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/pin" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="245 milles 22mb Baker Street London"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="8sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/cro" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="at Scroll Bar"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="8sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="0dip"`enter code here`
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".2" >
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when i run my apps it show StackOverflowError.those error show into logcat .....

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6739)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)`enter code here`
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.ja`enter code here`va:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1365)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3046)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6845)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2257)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6501)
at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6287)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1573)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:1923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)
at android.view.View`enter code here`Root.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
```

**Now,How i can solve this error please help to me..(I use htc 2.2 os device)**

Comment: your alyout is too complex and cluttered for what it does

Comment: Please provide the corresponding java source.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you MUST redefine your layout. You are making an improper use of `TableRow`. A `TableRow` should always be used as a child of a `TableLayout`.

I recommend you to read documentation about designing proper layouts in Android. There are very few uses for `TableLayout/TableRow` (but many people abuses of them as in web design, adding a lot of indesirable extra processing). Usually with a main `RelativeLayout` an a couple of inner `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` instances (trying not to nest a lot of them) you can achieve most of layouts.

Comment: I am not sure,why it show "StackOverflowError".You  told to me that it occurs only for proper layouts design.

Comment: ¿? I told what? I told you that you should first of all improve your layout, since you are not following Android recommendations. Get rid of most of the TableRow instances and try to simplify the definition of your layout, avoiding too many nested views. It's a possibility that the StackOverflowError comes from the fact that your layout is really too complex when it shouldn't be, consuming all memory on simple devices.

Answer (score 0):

### StackOverflowError

Thrown when the depth of the stack of the running program exceeds some platform or VM specific limit. Typically, this will occur only when a program becomes infinitely recursive, but it can also occur in correctly written (but deeply recursive) programs.